# No deflection in voltage regulator but the circuit works fine

Tags: circuit-design, voltage-regulator, ac, wire, home-automation

I have connected a voltage regulator **(range 0- 300V**) to my Air conditioner. The Air conditioner has three wires neutral,live and Earth. (I doubt if the connection is right). The Air conditioner turns on successfully after connecting to the regulator but the **there is no deflection in the voltage regulator**. (the needle always stays at 0V). Also the outside AC condenser doesn't start probably doesn't start cooling because of this.
I wanted to know if this could be **due to a wrong wire connection between AC and the voltage regulator** and what if the connection is right and i connect the wrong wires the regulator can it also affect the appliance?
And what could be the possible reasons for the voltage regulator showing no deflection and staying at 0V.

P.S - the voltage regulator and Air conditioner turn on fine and show a green light.

Image of the voltage regulator-
[image]

Comment: Is this actually a "Voltage Regulator", or is it a voltage monitor? (power line filter, power conditioner, watt meter, other name?).  Can you include a picture of the unit?

Comment: I have now added a picture of voltage regulator. its also called  a stabilizer (voltage stabilizer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a voltage stabilizer, it tries to maintain a stable line voltage going to the connected item. If you know the stabilizer unit worked earlier then it may be that you now have it wired incorrectly.

If the wiring is incorrect it may be possible you could damage the item being powered.  It is also possible that you could create a shock hazard, (especially if you cross a live wire connection with the ground wire).  Consult the user manual and carefully follow the connection instructions. If you don't have the manual or cannot follow the wiring then have a certified electrical contractor make the connections.

There would be a few incorrectly wired arrangements that may still allow the connected item to work normally. This might be the reason the meter is not working. But as I listed above there is a danger that some incorrect wire arrangements could be dangerous.